# Sorting 10k data set to the dict by child basis

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary, django-views

I have large data collection 10k objects. I want to sort it to the dict on the following way.

```
{
'code': obj.code, 'childs':[{
    'code': obj.code, 'childs':[{
        'code':obj.code, 'code':obj.code}] # no childs here
    }]
}
```

obj.code is 8 character string written as number

```
'01000000',
'01100000',
'01200000',
'21000000',
'21121200',
```

First two characters with 6 zero are 'root' parents so '01000000' and '21000000' are root parents.
Then '01100000', and '01400000' are first level child’s of '01' parent. Every parent can have 9 child’s max. So tree looks like this

```
01000000
    01100000
        01110000
            01111000
                01111100
                    01111110
                        01111111
                        01111112
                        01111113
                        01111114
                        01111115
                    01111120
                        01111121
                        01111122
                        01111123
                        01111124
                    01111130
                        01111131
                        01111132
                        01111133
                        01111134
                    01111140
                        01111141
                        01111142
                        01111143
                        01111144
```

I'm not sure from where to start, so any hint is much appreciated. Root parents can be found on this way.

```
def mySort(myQuerySet):
     root_parents = myQuerySet.objects(code__icontain='000000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. It iterates through the codes once to build a simple tree, then afterward turns that tree into the kind that you requested.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

def build_tree(codes):
    """Build the tree from a list of codes (strings)"""

    # tree is a dictionary that maps each code to a list of codes of children.
    tree = defaultdict(list)
    roots = []
    for code in codes:
        if '000000' in code:
            tree[code] = []
            roots.append(code)
        else:
            nonzero = re.search(r'[1-9]0*$', code).start()
            parent = code[:nonzero] + '0' + code[1 + nonzero:]
            tree[parent].append(code)

    # sort children (optional)
    for v in tree.values():
        v.sort()

    # convert original dictionary to one in the desired form.
    def convert(old_parent):
        result = {}
        result['code'] = old_parent
        if len(tree[old_parent]) > 0:
            result['children'] = [convert(c) for c in tree[old_parent]]
        return result

    return [convert(root) for root in roots]

codes = ["01000000", "01100000", "01110000", "01111000", "01111100", "01111110",
         "01111111", "01111112", "01111113", "01111114", "01111115", "01111120",
         "01111121", "01111122", "01111123", "01111124", "01111130", "01111131",
         "01111132", "01111133", "01111134", "01111140", "01111141", "01111142",
         "01111143", "01111144"]

pprint(build_tree(codes))
```

Here is the output (excuse the formatting)

```
[{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'code': '01111111'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111112'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111113'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111114'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111115'}],
                                                                        'code': '01111110'},
                                                                       {'children': [{'code': '01111121'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111122'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111123'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111124'}],
                                                                        'code': '01111120'},
                                                                       {'children': [{'code': '01111131'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111132'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111133'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111134'}],
                                                                        'code': '01111130'},
                                                                       {'children': [{'code': '01111141'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111142'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111143'},
                                                                                     {'code': '01111144'}],
                                                                        'code': '01111140'}],
                                                          'code': '01111100'}],
                                            'code': '01111000'}],
                              'code': '01110000'}],
                'code': '01100000'}],
  'code': '01000000'}]
```

Comment: Works really fine. Thank you very much!